# ArcObjects C#.Net 'System.NullReferenceException'

Tags: arcobjects, c#, visual-studio

I'm new to C# and ArcObjects. I just started a book and I'm getting introduced to it. My fist ever ArcObjects code is to create an extension that zooms to the full extent of an active layer. I have an error while debugging.
This is my code

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.BaseClasses;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.CATIDs;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI;

namespace ArcMapZTL
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for ZoomToActiveLayer.
    /// </summary>
    [Guid("7382c21f-249a-4bbe-84a3-3c3fd3d45c1b")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ProgId("ArcMapZTL.ZoomToActiveLayer")]
    public sealed class ZoomToActiveLayer : BaseCommand
    {

        #region"Zoom to Active Layer in TOC"
        // ArcGIS Snippet Title:
        // Zoom to Active Layer in TOC
        // 
        // Long Description:
        // Zooms to the selected layer in the Table of Contents (TOC) associated with the active view.
        // 
        // Add the following references to the project:
        // ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI
        // ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto
        // ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry
        // 
        // Intended ArcGIS Products for this snippet:
        // ArcGIS Desktop (ArcEditor, ArcInfo, ArcView)
        // 
        // Applicable ArcGIS Product Versions:
        // 9.2
        // 9.3
        // 9.3.1
        // 10.0
        // 
        // Required ArcGIS Extensions:
        // (NONE)
        // 
        // Notes:
        // This snippet is intended to be inserted at the base level of a Class.
        // It is not intended to be nested within an existing Method.
        // 

        ///<summary>Zooms to the selected layer in the TOC associated with the active view.</summary>
        /// 
        ///<param name="mxDocument">An IMxDocument interface</param>
        ///  
        ///<remarks></remarks>
        public void ZoomToActiveLayerInTOC(ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.IMxDocument mxDocument)
        {
            if (mxDocument == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IActiveView activeView = mxDocument.ActiveView;

            // Get the TOC
            ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.IContentsView IContentsView = mxDocument.CurrentContentsView;

            // Get the selected layer
            System.Object selectedItem = IContentsView.SelectedItem;
            if (!(selectedItem is ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.ILayer))
            {
                return;
            }
            ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.ILayer layer = selectedItem as ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.ILayer;


            // Zoom to the extent of the layer and refresh the map
            activeView.Extent = layer.AreaOfInterest;
            activeView.Refresh();
        }
        #endregion

        private IApplication m_application;
        public ZoomToActiveLayer()
        {
            //
            // TODO: Define values for the public properties
            //
            base.m_category = "ArcGISBook";
            base.m_caption = "Zooms To Active Layer";
            base.m_message = "Zooms To Active Layer inside TOC";
            base.m_toolTip = "Zooms To Active Layer inside TOC";
            base.m_name = "ZoomToActiveLayer";
            try
            {
                string bitmapResourceName = GetType().Name + ".bmp";
                base.m_bitmap = new Bitmap(GetType(), bitmapResourceName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message, "Invalid Bitmap");
            }
        }

        #region Overridden Class Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when this command is created
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hook">Instance of the application</param>
        public override void OnCreate(object hook)
        {
            if (hook == null)
                return;

            m_application = hook as IApplication;

            //Disable if it is not ArcMap
            if (hook is IMxApplication)
                base.m_enabled = true;
            else
                base.m_enabled = false;

            // TODO:  Add other initialization code
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when this command is clicked
        /// </summary>
        public override void OnClick()
        {
            // TODO: Add ZoomToActiveLayer.OnClick implementation
            IMxDocument mxdoc = m_application.Document as IMxDocument;
            ZoomToActiveLayerInTOC(mxdoc);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

The command does not load in ArcMap and I get this error in Visual Studio:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ESRI.APWR.AHConnectivity.dll
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ESRI.APWR.AHConnectivity.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

'ArcMap.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ESRI\WaterUtils\ArcHydro\bin\ESRI.APWR.ArcHydroTools.dll'. Symbols loaded.
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Invalid Bitmap: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Invalid Bitmap: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Invalid Bitmap: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Invalid Bitmap: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I use ArcGIS 10.3, Visual Studio Express 2013.

Comment: Which line of code does the error occur on?

Comment: I'm not certain this is as much an Arcobjects error as it is an error in loading a Bitmap object in general. How is the bitmap resource defined? Is it an embedded resource?